# Where is the download manager located on Xperia Z?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, sony-xperia-z

I'm using Xperia Z on Android 5.1.1. Normally, Download-Manager is an embedded app. This is why it is hard to find out its path.

What is the absolute path of Download-Manager?

Comment: It depends on what phone. Manufacturers often replace the built-in apps like the download manager with their own. Please [edit] your question to say what phone you're asking about.

Comment: @DanHulme Manufacturers often replace built-in apps, that's true. But no one should replace, let's say, System UI. For exactly the same reason Download Provider is rarely replaced.

Answer (score 2):

On Android 5.x (aka Lollipop) (also 6 and 7), its APK is located at

```
/system/priv-app/DownloadProvider/DownloadProvider.apk
```

Its data is located at

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.download/
```

Its default download location is (`$` = environmental variable)

```
$EXTERNAL_STORAGE/Downloads
```

Comment: -/Android/data/com.android.providers.download/ is not present in Xperia Z. And /system/priv-app is not present too. -

Comment: @dschinn1001 Download Provider, AFAIK, never store its data on SD cards. It only stores in `/data`. And if you claim that `/system/priv-app` does not exist, I will doubt if you're running Android 5.x.

Comment: @dschinn1001 You'd better not browse with the built-in file manager. It never shows the whole filesystem hierarchy, but only your **internal storage** (or SD card).

Answer (score -2):

Download-Manager is downloading your files to the folder `Downloads` which is located in the internal storage. 
Depending whether you have root access it should be at `/sdcard/Downloads` or in your internal storage at `~/Downloads`.